# creating a google map that is connected to database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to create a google map. the latitude and the longitude are from the database so I had to put those in a textbox then get its value in the script. I tried doing so but it doesn't work will you help me with this one; here's my JavaScript:

```
function initMap() {

        var lat = document.getElementById('lat');
        var lang = document.getElementById('lang');

    var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lang };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" id="lat" value="7.8383054" />
<input type="text" style="display: none" id="lang" value="123.2966657" />

<div id="map" ">
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mttqcer/)

Comment: where do you call the `onload` function?

Comment: nothing, i just tried it. but it still wont work even without the onload function, just the getElementById.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the "numbers" in the text fields are access using the .value property:
2. the lat/lng in a google.maps.LatLngLiteral must be numbers.  (without the parseFloat the API throws these errors:

   - InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
   - InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

```
var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value);
var lang = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lang').value);
```

3. You need to actually call the initMap method (your fiddle isn't doing this)

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1mttqcer/1/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<input type="text" id="lat" value="7.8383054" />
<input type="text" id="lang" value="123.2966657" />

<div id="map" ">
</div>
<script>
function initMap() {

        var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value);
        var lang = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lang').value);

    var uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lang };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. i can now sleep!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
var lang = document.getElementById('lang').value;
```

Comment: It will be much easier if you could create a JSFilddle example or send a link to the website.

Comment: how to? i dont know how to create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure where your problem lies aside from not actually using the value of the text inputs or calling the function that returns those values but perhaps something long these lines might help get you started. If you are needing the user to enter different lat/lng coordinates then you would also need an event handler assigned to listen for changes or a button to submit the new coordinates.

```
<?php
    /*

    */
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google maps</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <script src='https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            function initMap() {
                var uluru = {
                    lat: document.getElementById('lat').value,
                    lng: document.getElementById('lang').value
                };
                var options={
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: uluru
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: uluru,
                    map: map
                });
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initMap, false );
        </script>
        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'></style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='map'></div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' id='lat' value='7.8383054' />
            <input type='text' id='lang' value='123.2966657' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: those textboxes are hidden cause their vaues are coming from the database

Comment: If the values are coming from a db then why add the extra layer of bloat by using text fields and retrieving the values that way - better to use PHP to write the js variables directly

Answer (score 0):

call  initMap() function in body tag. it will load the map, the most important thing do you have api key ? you also need ssl to use google maps. means your url must be https://yourdomain.com

body onload="initMap()"